# Select index pandas Series by a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I have this:

```
Wochentag
Mo    1083
Di     913
Mi    1125
Do    1797
Fr    2129
Name: Besucher, dtype: int64
```

I just want to select the "Di" because 913 is the lowest number. Therefore I tried:

```
df.loc[df.min()] - but I always get an error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
df['Besucher'].idxmin()
```